# Отправка писем Django

Tags: python, django

Не отправляет письмо с формы

settings.py

```
EMAIL_HOST = 'smtp.yandex.ru'
EMAIL_HOST_USER = 'my mail'
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = 'password'
EMAIL_PORT = 587
EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

views.py

```
def get_data(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = MyForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
           print('Hi')
           e_mail = send_mail('Заказ от {0}'.format(form.name), form.phone_number, 'my mail', ['to mail'])
           if e_mail == True:
              print(e_mail)
              return HttpResponseRedirect('/done/')
           else:
              return HttpResponse('<h1>Ошибка сообщение не отправлено<h1>')
    else:
        form = MyForm()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form':form})
```

С shell возвращает 1 
при от правки с формы с сайта возвращает такое:

> A server error occurred.  Please contact the administrator.

и переходит на такой url:

> /done/

работаю с мака

Comment: без print ошибка так же есть?

Comment: Да, принт добавил чтобы смотреть заходить ли в блок или нет?